# how to find byte index in string in java

Tags: java, string

I have string and there is `0x80` in it. string presentation is : `serialno�` and hex presentation is `73 65 72 69 61 6C 6E 6F 80`. I want to remove `0x80` from string without convert string to hex string. is it possible in java ? I tried `lastIndexOf(0x80)`. but it returns -1.

my code is (also you can find on https://ideone.com/3p8wKT) :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String hexValue = "73657269616C6E6F80";
    String binValue = hexStringToBin(hexValue);
    System.out.println("binValue : " + binValue);

    int index = binValue.lastIndexOf(0x80);

    System.out.println("index : " + index);
}

public static String hexStringToBin(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));
    }
    return new String(data);
}
```

Comment: "and hex presentation is" - how have you determined that? Please provide a [mcve]. I suspect your string *actually* contains U+FFFD, the Unicode replacement character, but it's not certain at the moment. Additionally, it may well be better to clean the data earlier, before converting it to a string.

Comment: You should probably us a charset when you return `new String(data);` You have some bytes and they'll get translated into characters which could have a different value than the raw byte value.

Comment: General comment: don't try to create a string like this to represent arbitrary binary data. That's not what it's there for. I'd expect a `hexStringToBin` method to return a `byte[]`, not a `String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your hex string method to map directly to characters.

```
char[] data = new char[len / 2];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
    data[i / 2] = (char) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));
}

return new String(data);
```

The exchange between a String and byte[] requires an encoding.

Your hex string seems to be a string representation of bytes/characters. It would appear you had an original String -> converted it to your hex string, but we don't know the encoding.

If you want to say that each pair of characters maps to the corresponding character, eg "80" -> char c = 0x80; Then you can achieve that by using a char[], which doesn't get encoded/decoded when creating a string.

If you use a byte[] (as you have done in your example), then it will get decoded and invalid characters get mapped to 0xFFFD, which is [unicode replacement character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm).

Answer (score 1):

It's because you converted `�` symbol to hex incorrectly (`0x80`). 1 symbol in `UTF-8` can take 1 byte or more. In your case `�` symbol takes 2 bytes and have the following representation `65533` or `0xFFFD`. So, if you replace your code with

```
int index = variable.lastIndexOf(0xFFFD);
//index will be 8
```

all will work fine.

Code snippet to proof my words:

```
String variable = "serialno�";
for (char c : variable.toCharArray())
    System.out.print(((int)c)+ " ");
// 115 101 114 105 97 108 110 111 65533
```

**UPDATE**

You've made a mistake in `hexStringToBin` function. Replace it with

```
public static String hexStringToBin(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    char[] data = new char[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (char) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));
    }

    return new String(data);
}
```

and all will work fine.

Comment: I tried it for other two bytes variables like 0x81,0x82... all is represent as 65533. but i am looking for only 0x80

Comment: @user4757345 it is because the charset you are using to create the string maps all of those values to an invalid character.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me :

```
int hex = 0x6F;
System.out.println("serialno€".lastIndexOf((char)hex));
```

Output :

```
7
```

Comment: in char `0x80` is unknown in ASCII table could you tell me which encoding it is ?